# Siamese model accuracy stuck at 0.5

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, siamese-networks

I'm trying to train a Siamese Network model for a signatures dataset using Keras API and considering the loss only seems not bad. But ironically enough the model accuracy stuck at 0.5.

Model Loss:

[image: Model Loss]

Model Accuracy:

[image: Model Accuracy]

My model is kind of a deep model, here's its architecture:

```
input = Input((128, 128, 1))

x = BatchNormalization()(input)
x = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation="tanh")(x)
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation="tanh")(x)
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation="tanh")(x)
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (2, 2), activation="tanh")(x)
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (2, 2), activation="tanh")(x)
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)

x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(10, activation="tanh", kernel_regularizer="l2")(x)

embedding_network = Model(input, x)

input_1 = Input((128, 128, 1))
input_2 = Input((128, 128, 1))

tower_1 = embedding_network(input_1)
tower_2 = embedding_network(input_2)

merge_layer = Lambda(euclidean_distance)([tower_1, tower_2])
normal_layer = BatchNormalization()(merge_layer)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(normal_layer)

siamese = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output_layer)
```

The model takes grayscale 128x128 images of signatures in batches of 16 images using the ImageDataGenerator class having 800 training samples and 200 validation samples and trains in 15 epochs. The optimizer function is RMSprop at learning rate of 0.001 and the loss function is Contrasive Loss with margin of 0.5.

What did I miss and why doesn't my model learning?

Comment: Is this binary classification? Is the dataset balanced? I don't know anything about DL and images, but I would start by looking at a confusion matrix to understand what happens: does the model always predict the same class across epochs? And if so why is the loss changing at all? It could be a bug somewhere.

Comment: How did you write the loss function? and how did you build your training triplets?

Comment: @Oscar its the contrasive loss function:

square_pred = tf.math.square(y_pred)
margin_square = tf.math.square(tf.math.maximum(margin - (y_pred), 0))
return tf.math.reduce_mean(
    (1 - y_true) * square_pred + (y_true) * margin_square
)

Comment: @Erwan its a siamese network it measures the similarity of two images and compares the predicted similarity with the defined similarity (0 non-similar or 1 similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was hidden in the loss function. I decided to change it from Contrasive Loss to Categorical Crossentropy just for fun, and with some kind of "magic" it worked.

from:

```
def loss(margin=1):
  def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    square_pred = tf.math.square(y_pred)
    margin_square = tf.math.square(tf.math.maximum(margin - (y_pred), 0))
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(
        (1 - y_true) * square_pred + (y_true) * margin_square
    )

  return contrastive_loss

siamese.compile(loss=loss(margin=MARGIN), optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

to:

```
siamese.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=["accuracy"])
```